# how to solve the following error in rally tool?

Tags: rally

Whenever i move from one release(ex: release-1) to another release (ex: release-2) by using release dropdown button, i am getting this error( in rally 1.26 and 1.27 versions not in 1.22). how to solve this problem? please send your reply to my mail. 
My mail ID: ramesh_yenda@dell.com

Error: Tried to register widget with id==tableGrid but that id is already registered
https://pg-rally.us.dell.com/apps/1.26/component_10-03-2011.js
Line 16

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by a change in the behavior of the table component between early versions of the App SDK where the table would automatically clean itself up and later ones where it would not.

Please see this example: [developer.rallydev.com/help/ui-examples#iteration](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/ui-examples#iteration) (Specifically the onIterationSelected function where you can see the table being destroyed before being recreated).